# How can I make javascript automatically scroll and make a scroll bar in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm having trouble making my website have a scroll bar and make it automatically scroll. It's a simple chat website, it's just a simple project.

This is the website: https://chat.jchs.repl.co/

You can fork the code with this (you have to make an account first): https://replit.com/@jchs/chat#html/index.html

If you would like to see the index.html code before making a comment:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Chat </title>
    <meta name = "charset" charset = "utf-8">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css">
    <script src = "script.js"></script>
    <script src= "socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload = "onload()">
    <div id = "Main">
      <audio id = "Ding" src = "Ding.mp3"> </audio>
      <h1 id = "Title"> Online Chat </h1>
      <div id = "AccessPort">
        <label id = "NameLabel"> Username  </label>
        <input id = "NameInput" type = "text">
        <br><br>
        <label id = "IDLabel"> Chatroom </label>
        <input id = "IDInput" value = "Room1" type = "text">
        <input id = "ConnectButton" class = "Button" type = "submit" value = "Connect" onclick = "Connect()">
      </div>
      <h2 id = "RoomID"> Chatroom : None </h2>
      <div id = "Chat">
        <p id = "Message0" class = "Message"> - </p>
        <p id = "Message1" class = "Message"> - </p>
        <p id = "Message2" class = "Message"> - </p>
        <p id = "Message3" class = "Message"> - </p>
        <p id = "Message4" class = "Message"> - </p>
        <p id = "Message5" class = "Message"> - </p>
        <p id = "Message6" class = "Message"> - </p>
        <p id = "Message7" class = "Message"> - </p>
        <p id = "Message8" class = "Message"> - </p>
        <p id = "Message9" class = "Message"> - </p>
        <label id = "MessageLabel"> Message </label>
        <input id = "ComposedMessage" type = "text">
        <input id = "SendMessage" onclick="Send()" value = "Send" class = "Button" type = "submit">
      </div>
      <br><br>
    </div>
    <p2>No racism, homophobia, or any -isms or -phobias. No impersonating or trying to be someone else. Use common sense. </p2>
    <p id="counter">Users online: <span id="userCount">Loading…</span></p>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $().ready(function (){
      var token = '';
      var pinger = setInterval(function (){
        
        $.ajax({
          cache: false,
          data: {
            token: token,
          },
          timeout: 2500,
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'pinger.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function (data, status, jqXHR){
            $('#userCount').text(data.userCount);
            token = data.token;
          }
        });
        
      }, 3000);
    });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'll keep the website open for a couple more hours if you guys would like to take your time. Remember that you can always fork it and run it on your own account.

Answer (score 1):

Your chat has several problems. Let's try to solve:

First, you have a fixed number of messages. Your chat div must start empty and when you receive a message, you add a new p tag with the message. Now, after you send several messages, you get an error on "document.getElementById("Message"+i)" sentence.

Try putting the inputs outside the chat's messages part:

```
<div id="Chat" style="overflow-y:scroll;height:200px">
     <p id="Message0" class="Message" style="color: rgb(48, 48, 48);"></p>
     ...
     <p id="Message9" class="Message" style="color: rgb(48, 48, 48);"></p>
</div>
<label id="MessageLabel"> Message </label>
<input id="ComposedMessage" type="text">
<input id="SendMessage" onclick="Send()" value="Send" class="Button" type="submit">
```

In this way, you can add overflow-y:scroll style to your Chat div. And you need set some fixed height to your chat. Maybe 200px, 75%, 75vh... depending of your preferences.

You can go to bottom with this code:

```
var chat = document.getElementById('Chat');
chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;
```

You can see this page to check how to style the scrollbar: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp

Comment: Thank you for this reply, Victor.

This code does seem to work, but I was thinking more of a 'Compacted' text, and only scrolling down when a new chat is sent, but being freely to move the scrollbar for the chat up and down.

Comment: Of course. You can set scrollTop when you want. For example when receive a message. Or, you can check first your position (if scrollTop==scrollHeight you are at bottom), then add the received message and, only if you was at bottom, set againt the scrollTop at bottom. In this form, if you are scrolling, the chat don't go to bottom on new messages